# Need help understanding "getbits()" method in Chapter 2 of K&R C

Tags: c, operators, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, complement

In chapter 2, the section on bitwise operators (section 2.9), I'm having trouble understanding how one of the sample methods works.

Here's the method provided:

```
unsigned int getbits(unsigned int x, int p, int n) {
    return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) & ~(~0 << n);
}
```

The idea is that, for the given number *x*, it will return the *n* bits starting at position *p*, counting from the right (with the farthest right bit being position 0). Given the following `main()` method:

```
int main(void) {
    int x = 0xF994, p = 4, n = 3;
    int z = getbits(x, p, n);
    printf("getbits(%u (%x), %d, %d) = %u (%X)\n", x, x, p, n, z, z);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> `getbits(63892 (f994), 4, 3) = 5 (5)`

I get portions of this, but am having trouble with the "big picture," mostly because of the bits (no pun intended) that I don't understand.

The part I'm specifically having issues with is the complements piece: `~(~0 << n)`. I think I get the first part, dealing with *x*; it's this part (and then the mask) that I'm struggling with -- and how it all comes together to actually retrieve those bits. (Which I've verified it is doing, both with code and checking my results using calc.exe -- thank God it has a binary view!)

Any help?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Let's use 16 bits for our example. In that case, `~0` is equal to

```
1111111111111111
```

When we left-shift this `n` bits (3 in your case), we get:

```
1111111111111000
```

because the `1`s at the left are discarded and `0`s are fed in at the right. Then re-complementing it gives:

```
0000000000000111
```

so it's just a clever way to get `n` 1-bits in the least significant part of the number.

The "x bit" you describe has shifted the given number (`f994 = 1111 1001 1001 0100`) right far enough so that the least significant 3 bits are the ones you want. In this example, the input bits you're requesting are there, all other input bits are marked `.` since they're not important to the final result:

```
ff94             ...........101..  # original number
>> p+1-n     [2] .............101  # shift desired bits to right
& ~(~0 << n) [7] 0000000000000101  # clear all the other (left) bits
```

As you can see, you now have the relevant bits, in the rightmost bit positions.

Comment: I was going to suggest right shifting, to save an instruction, but I guess, `~(~0 << n)` elegantly lets you ignore the word size you are working with...

Comment: I don't understand something, where do I wrong? int a = 0; so printf("%d", a) gives 0. Now, a = ~a so printf("%d", a) gives -1, why?

Comment: @Anatoly: it's because `~` inverts all bits to 1 and, in twos complement encoding, that's -1.

Comment: Great answer. I finally understand this example! :)

Comment: Thanks for that great answer @paxdiablo. However, in order to fully grasp every step along the way I woul like to be able to isolate every step. For when I try to print `printf("try: %d\n", ~0 << 1);`,  I get an error: `printf("try: %d\n", ~0 << 1); ~~ ^ 1 warning generated.  Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_printnozero", referenced from: _main in getbits-923932.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`. Is there another way to print it out. If not why can't I print it out?

Answer (score 14):

I would say the best thing to do is to do a problem out by hand, that way you'll understand how it works.

Here is what I did using an 8-bit unsigned int.

1. Our number is 75 we want the 4 bits starting from position 6.
   the call for the function would be getbits(75,6,4);
2. 75 in binary is 0100 1011
3. So we create a mask that is 4 bits long starting with the lowest order bit this is done as such.

~0 = 1111 1111
<<4 = 1111 0000
~ = 0000 1111

Okay we got our mask.

4. Now, we push the bits we want out of the number into the lowest order bits so
   we shift binary 75 by 6+1-4=3.

0100 1011 >>3  0000 1001

Now we have a mask of the correct number of bits in the low order and the bits we want out of the original number in the low order.

4. so we & them

```
  0000 1001 

& 0000 1111
============

  0000 1001
```

so the answer is decimal 9.

**Note:** the higher order nibble just happens to be all zeros, making the masking redundant in this case but it could have been anything depending on the value of the number we started with.

Answer (score 7):

`~(~0 << n)` creates a mask that will have the `n` right-most bits turned on.

```
0
   0000000000000000
~0
   1111111111111111
~0 << 4
   1111111111110000
~(~0 << 4)
   0000000000001111
```

ANDing the result with something else will return what's in those `n` bits.

Edit: I wanted to point out this programmer's calculator I've been using forever: [AnalogX PCalc](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Programming/pcalc/Freeware.htm).

Answer (score 4):

Nobody mentioned it yet, but in ANSI C `~0 << n` causes undefined behaviour.

This is because `~0` is a negative number and left-shifting negative numbers is undefined.

Reference: C11 6.5.7/4 (earlier versions had similar text)

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. [...] If E1 has a signed
>   type and nonnegative value, and `E1` × `2`<sup>`E2`</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

In K&R C this code would have relied on the particular class of system that K&R developed on, naively shifting `1` bits off the left when performing left-shift of a signed number (and this code also relies on 2's complement representation),  but some other systems don't share those properties so the C standardization process did not define this behaviour.

So this example is really only interesting as a historical curiosity, it should not be used in any real code since 1989 (if not earlier).

Answer (score 2):

Using the example:
int x = 0xF994, p = 4, n = 3;
    int z = getbits(x, p, n);

and focusing on this set of operations
   ~(~0 << n)

for any bit set (10010011 etc) you want to generate a "mask" that pulls only the bits you want to see.  So 10010011 or 0x03, I'm interested in xxxxx011. What is the mask that will extract that set ?  00000111  Now I want to be sizeof int independent, I'll let the machine do the work i.e. start with 0  for a byte machine it's 0x00 for a word machine it's 0x0000 etc.  64 bit machine would represent by 64 bits or 0x0000000000000000

Now apply "not" (~0) and get 11111111
shift right (<<) by n and get 11111000
and "not" that and get 00000111

so 10010011 & 00000111 = 00000011

 You remember how boolean operations work ?

Comment: @jim: Hey, not knocking the accuracy of you post. Content wise has more to go on than either of the other two, it would be good to use codeblocks and align changes. The posts use wiki markup, and a tute page links off the "?" above the answer box. I had to read it twice to be able to check it.

Answer (score -1):

In `ANSI C ~0 >> n` causes undefined behavior

// the post about left shifting causing a problem is wrong.

unsigned char m,l;

m = ~0 >> 4; is producing 255 and its equal to ~0 but,

m = ~0;
l = m >> 4; is producing correct value 15 same as:

m = 255 >> 4;

there is no problem with left shifting negative `~0 <<` whatsoever